# Java ProcessBuilder run npm command Not Working

Tags: java, macos, npm, processbuilder

**Using Mac Mini Server**

My Java Code 1 :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("npm");
p.waitFor();
```

My Java Code 2 :

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("npm run build")
  directory(new File(path))
  .start();
p.waitFor();
```

My Java Code 3 :

```
// npmBuilder.sh => npm run build
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash npmBuilder.sh");
p.waitFor();
```

Allways same Error :

```
node:child_process:173
  p.open(fd);
    ^

Error: ENOTTY: inappropriate ioctl for device, uv_pipe_open
    at Object._forkChild (node:child_process:173:5)
    at setupChildProcessIpcChannel (node:internal/process/pre_execution:465:30)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/process/pre_execution:78:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:10:1 {
  errno: -25,
  code: 'ENOTTY',
  syscall: 'uv_pipe_open'
}
```

I don't understand what's going on here

Comment: A good start would be to read the process output to better understand what is going on. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809404/829571

Comment: Works for me when I just call `npm` in an empty directory. Can you [edit] and add a [mcve] to your question? In particular, what happens when you run the npm commands without going through Java? Is there anything special with the npm setup?